# Visual glitch on all StackExchange sites in the timeline of rep changes

Tags: bug, profile-page

For a few months now, but introduced this year, in Opera (12.x) the timeline of reputation changes looks awkward. See this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see the timeline stretches onto two lines and therefore overlaps with the list of rep changes.

Comment: Nobody outside Europe uses **Opera**

Comment: Can't reproduce in any real browsers

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have the same issue with Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m